# SearchPathW freezing

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am attempting to write a function that will be able to find an arbitrary executable located in the executable search path on my system. I'm encountering an issue where some inputs will cause `SearchPathW` to freeze indefinitely, and I'm not sure what exactly is going on.

```
std::optional<std::wstring> SearchPathExecutable(const std::wstring& name){
    auto size = SearchPathW(nullptr, name.c_str(), L".exe", 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    if(!size){
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    std::vector<WCHAR> buffer(static_cast<size_t>(size) + 1 );
    WCHAR* filename{};
    if(!SearchPathW(nullptr, name.c_str(), L".exe", size + 1, buffer.data(), &filename)){
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    return buffer.data();
}
```

When name is `L"--autoruns"` (which is not current a file in my search path), the code freezes at the first call to `SearchPathW`, and the call never returns.

The obvious solution here would be "Oh, well just don't search for files that don't exist!" Unfortunately, that is not an option since one of the intended usages of this function is to determine if the file is in fact present in the search path. Since I could place a file called "--autoruns.exe" inside the C:\Windows directory, it's not just something I can filter out.

What can I do to either prevent this hang, avoid the call to SearchPathW altogether, or catch and remediate this hang?

I have already attempted to create a new thread to handle the call to SearchPathW and `WaitForSingleObject` it with a delay of 1000 ms. For some reason, that also hung.

After running procmon, it seems that the issue is that it keeps re-searching the path.
[image]

I have found a few other filenames that also cause this same issue, making me doubt there is some symlink/hardlink causing this. I've also checked my PATH against the file paths it's checking, and it checks every location in my PATH before repeating.

Comment: Off topic, but it is safer to use `std::vector<WCHAR> buffer(size + 1)` than to use `new[]`.  Not only will it prevent a memory leak, you could simply just say `return buffer.data()` instead of storing it in a temporary string.

Comment: Also, `WCHAR* ext = L".exe";` is not valid C++.  It should be `const WCHAR* ext = L".exe";`

Comment: ah, wonder why my compiler didn't catch that one! And thanks for the tip!

Comment: Your manual check for a file extension is unnecessary since `SearchFileW()` ignores its `lpExtension` parameter if the `lpFileName` parameter includes a file extension.  This is [documented behavior](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-searchpathw). As for the hang, try using SysInternals [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which file it is getting hung on exactly, and [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see which process(es) use that file.

Comment: turns out it wasn't actually a deadlock; instead it just keeps trying again and again...

Comment: @JamesMcDowell Just wondering, are you running your application with Admin rights?  If not, would there be any difference if you did run it with elevated rights?

Comment: It is running as admin. All files in the search path should have read access

Comment: It would be helpful to expand the left column of the procmon so the timestamps are visible.  Does it keep spamming searches forever or does procmon stop at some point?

Comment: also it would improve the question to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as then anyone can copy paste and try to reproduce. Check that your MRE actually exhibits the problem when run

Comment: @JamesMcDowell I wonder if there is a symlink/hardlink somewhere on your search path that happens to be pointing to another path also on the search path, creating a recursive loop.

Comment: It endlessly loops. I have created no such hardlink/symlink, and this issue has occurred with other file names.

Comment: You're using a registry-dependent system search path, have you tried to call SetSearchPathMode first see if i changes anything?

Comment: *A stack trace shows me that it's hanging in the syscall to `ZwQueryAttributesFile`* - paste name of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by a higher level function calling this one in a loop with an unreachable break condition, and the debugger just happened to always show it stuck on SearchPathW. Resolved.